# Как интегрировать Spring в intellij idea community edition?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc, maven

Решил сделать свое первое приложение на Spring+Maven и никак не могу понять как Spring установить/добавить в мою ИДЕЮ. 
Следуя одному из видео уроков по mvc, создал проект Maven и добавил следующую dependency (я так понял это что-то типа либы, только для Maven?):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Сначала, строка org.springframework выделилась красным, сославшись,на то что нужно что-то загрузить/обновить, что я и сделал через Alt-Enter. В итоге закачалось чего-то на 271 мб и благополучно установилось.

Далее в уроке создают класс-контроллер в `src/main/java` и начинают добавлять туда аннотацию `@Controller`, которая в свою очередь подтягивает различные импорты из пакета org.springframework.*. Так вот - ни аннотации, ни этих импортов моя идея не находит и не подгружает.

Что я сделал не так или, может, не сделал вообще?
Заранее спсибо.

Comment: Так в идее вроде изначально есть шаблон для создания приложений с использованием spring.  Если же такого не окажется, то вросто надо плагин подключить

Comment: одной библиотеки spring-mvc упомянутой выше вроде как может быть мало. возможно необходимо spring core и еще несколько. [тут](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/) и [здесь](http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/) можно посмотреть пример, а так же увидеть какие еще зависимости необходимо добавить в `pom.xml`

Comment: I. Smirnov, а не подскажете имя плагина?)
...добавил еще spring-core и spring-web, но не помогло

Comment: прошу прощения. немного ввел в заблуждение. Это поддержк плагинов возможно касалась `ultimate edition`, а не `community`. Так что может проще будет поискать `UE`)

Comment: Если вы только начинаете изучение, то обратите внимание на [Spring boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).
Для простых задач достаточно будет забрать `spring-boot-starter-web` все остальные зависимости там уже есть. Далее можно будет "оптимизировать"набор зависимостей по мере погружения.

Comment: Закачайте по ссылке и установите https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/download-thanks.html?platform=windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Controller` находится в пакете `org.springframework.stereotype.Controller`, депеденси на который можно поставить следующим образом:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Idea Community Edition поддерживает работу со спрингом. В Ultimate Edition она проста усовершенстовована, добавлена автоматизация некоторых вещей. Из того, что я заметил: удобная навигация по бинам и out-of-the-box поддержка всех компонентов спринга, таких как spring-boot, например.

Comment: Верно! Я наконец нашел откуда скачать все jar'ники: http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/
Всем спасибо!

Comment: cadmy, вы поправили депенденси на spring-webmvc, но как раз там и не находило @Controller.
Вообще правильно ли я понимаю, что есть 2 способа добавить Spring в идею?: 1) напрямую скачать jar и добавить его в качестве библиотеки проекта 2)через добавление  депеденси  в pom с последующим импортом-зарузкой

Comment: Ну, в принципе, да. Первый способ используюется если нет автоматического сборщика проекта (maven), второй более приемлимый в текущих реалиях.

Comment: А почему тогда, когда я добавил депеденси spring-webmvc у меня не появилась поддержка пакета org.springframework.stereotype.Controller ?

Comment: Пакет, который вы указали в начале правильный. Может нужно было подождать когда идея проиндексирует все. И там окно еще всплывает об автоматическом обновлении изменений в мавене.

Comment: так я сутки ждал и ничего)  и пока напрямую не закачал jar-файлы не заработало, странно...
а сама idea что-то загрузила, но все-равно не видела Controller

Comment: Есть подозрение что что-то с мавеном не так. У вас в поме ничего красным не подчеркнуто?

Comment: нет, только в самом начале подчеркнуло org.springframework, но как я уже сказал, потом все само загрузилось

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38268/discussion-between-cadmy-and-svorobei).